# Tag for cleanup - finger

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[finger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/finger) - Usage seems to roughly equally divided between the *nix command and the digit of one's hand.

Perhaps we can break this up into 2 separate tags? Or even remove the references to physical limbs since those questions can probably be tagged just as well with touch, touchpad etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed it from the questions that were referring to the hand and updated the tag wiki to make it clear that it should be used for the name/finger protocol.